# Node.js Function returns Undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a function with node.js that checks the hash of an online file to see if it's been changed. Every time I call my function it always returns undefined. I understand the problem has something to do with asynchronous functions, but I don't quite understand how they work.

```js
const crypto = require("crypto")
const request = require("request") 

function checkHash(url, hash) {
    request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (crypto.createHash('md5').update(body).digest("hex") !== hash) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't return any value. Check for promises in JS.

Comment: You cannot return 'values' from an asynchronous functions. Instead you should call the 'callback' function with the required value or error. You must go through basic Javascript tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being an async call you must provide a way to rescue back your returned value. A possible approach are using `callbacks` as below:

```
const crypto = require("crypto")
const request = require("request") 

function checkHash(url, hash, callback) {
    request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (crypto.createHash('md5').update(body).digest("hex") !== hash) {
                return callback(null, true);
            } else {
                return callback(null, false);
            }
        }
        return callback(error);
    });
}
```

then call `chechHash` passing a function as argument:

```
checkHash(url, hash, function(err, response) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    //response is here
})
```